# Select clause inside IN with TypeORM

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have a pretty simple sql query:

```
select * from comments c
inner join users u on u.id = c.user_id
where user_id = 1 OR (c.user_id IN (select user_id_one from friends f where user_id_two = 1))
```

I am having a lot of trouble getting this translated into TypeORM, specifically this part:

```
c.user_id IN (select user_id_one from friends f where user_id_two = 1)
```

No where is it clear on how to use the IN operator along with a inner select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Where` statement and inside that add something like this:

```
query.where((queryBuilder: SelectQueryBuilder<YOUR_ENTITY>) => {
    queryBuilder.where('alias.id in' +
        queryBuilder.subQuery()
            .select('a.id')
            .from(YOUR_ENTITY, 'a')
            .getQuery(),
    )
})
// ...
```